# Привязка редактора Gutenberg к кастомному типу поста

Tags: wordpress

При регистрации кастомного типа записи в WP для поддержки визуального редактора мы указываем аргумент `'supports' => array('editor', ...)`. Но при этом добавляется классический визуальный редактор, а не Gutenberg, как в стандартных записях.

В документации не нашел, что нужно указать, чтобы добавлялся он.

Comment: show in rest = true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если мне не изменяет память, при добавлении нового типа записи попробуйте указать в функции `register_post_type('your type', array('show_in_rest' => true))`